# newsletter email show either on mobile or desktop in Outlook 2013

Tags: email, mobile, outlook, desktop, newsletter

I'm having an issue when I insert html file as text into Outlook 2013. The presentation of the mail is fine It just seems that the directives I have given based on whether mobile or desktop don't seem to apply when I resize the browser when viewing Outlook. The show hide functionality works fine if showing html file in normal browser window outside of Outlook 2013.

I have tried this:

```
  <style>

    #outlook a {padding:0;}     
    body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}     
    .ReadMsgBody {width: 100%;}
    .ExternalClass {width:100%;} 
    .backgroundTable {margin:0 auto; padding:0; width:100%;!important;} 
    table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
    .ExternalClass * {line-height: 115%;}

    span.show { display: none; }


    /* End reset */
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px){

        *[class="container"] { width: 320px !important; padding:0px !important}                                 
        *[class="mobile-column"] {display: block;}
        *[class="mob-column"] {float: none !important;width: 100% !important;}         
        *[class="mobile-padding"] {padding-left:10px !important;padding-right:10px !important;}         
        *[class="hide"] {display:none !important;}          
        *[class="100p"] {width:100% !important; height:auto !important;}            

        *[class="show"] {
             overflow: visible !important;
             float: none !important;
             display: block !important;
             line-height:100% !important;
            }



    }



     </style>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mobile-padding" bgcolor="#EFEFEF" style="background-color: #EFEFEF; margin: 0; padding: 0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="100p" width="600">
                <tr>
                    <td height="10"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="right" style="font-size:11px; color:#333333; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Email looking strange? <a href="##" style="color:#ad2f70; text-decoration:none;">View it in browser</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="100p" width="600">
                <tr>
                    <td height="20"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>


            <table width="600" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" class="100p" border="0" bgcolor="#E4E4E5">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="font-size:18px; color:#333333; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Hello!<span class="hide"><br /><br />This text is viewable on a larger screen.</span>

  <span class="show" style="overflow:hidden; float:left; display:none; line-height:0px;"><br />This is hidden on desktop!</span>
 </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="100p" width="600">
                <tr>
                    <td height="20"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is a sample bit of code I took form a working demon I saw online but when I embed into Outlook 2013 and send a test mail it doesn't apply. I just open the mail up and resize the browser window to mobile size but none content doesn't seem to apply for mobile. In terms of mobile responsiveness for emails, do I need to test on actual device. Will change not display when resizing window on desktop.

Thanks and any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook 2013, 2016 and 2007 do not work with `@media` queries.

This is a full list of email clients that do not work with `@media` queries and is a great guide to what works with the current state of email.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/media-queries/media/
- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Good luck with your email.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Office Outlook uses the HTML parsing and rendering engine from Microsoft Office Word to display HTML message bodies. The same HTML and cascading style sheets (CSS) support available in Word is available in Outlook. 
This following articles provide reference documentation related to supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)